# SQL Union of columns from same subquery into a single one

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I want to select a single column given as the union of the content in cols 1, 2, 3, 4 of the same table. Since `SUBQUERY` and `CONDITION` are complicated I have the feeling that this is the wrong way to go for it:

```
SELECT COL1 FROM SUBQUERY WHERE CONDITION 
UNION
SELECT COL2 FROM SUBQUERY WHERE CONDITION 
UNION
SELECT COL3 FROM SUBQUERY WHERE CONDITION 
UNION
SELECT COL4 FROM SUBQUERY WHERE CONDITION 
UNION
SELECT COL5 FROM SUBQUERY WHERE CONDITION
```

Since this query looks bad both performance-wise and from the point of view of good coding style, Is there a better syntax in Oracle?

P.S.

If only the following pseudo code were correct... it would be perfect:

```
SELECT COL1 UNION COL2 UNION COL3 UNION COL4 
FROM 
    SUBQUERY WHERE CONDITION;
```

Comment: Your syntax (top) looks fine, and rather I would question your database design which led to having apparently similar information in different columns for some reason.

Comment: Are those `SUBQUERY` the same? only different on `WHERE CONDITION`

Comment: May be using `with` clause could help a little. `with SUBQUERY  as (select ... ) SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ...`

Comment: @D-Shih the conditions as well are the same. I am going to try the query suggested by Plirkee (who could make an answer of his comment).

Comment: `DISTINCT` on `UNION` is superfluous.   A `UNION` operation removes duplicates. did you mean `UNION ALL` ?

Comment: Whilst the union (or union all) approach would work, it does mean you're querying the same table multiple times. I prefer Dmitry's unpivot answer, which would only require one hit on the table and should therefore be more performant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `UNPIVOT`:

```
select * from 
    (select 'a' col1, 'b' col2, 'c' col3, 'd' col4, 'e' col5 from dual)
unpivot (
  united_columns for subquery_column in ("COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4", "COL5"));

SUBQUERY_COLUMN UNITED_COLUMNS
--------------- --------------
COL1            a              
COL2            b              
COL3            c              
COL4            d              
COL5            e
```

Place your `select * from subquery where condition` istead of

```
select 'a' col1, 'b' col2, 'c' col3, 'd' col4, 'e' col5 from dual
```

More information about `UNPIVOT` to get the idea: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Answer (score 3):

if the condition and sub-queries are the same for all columns then you could probably use the following syntax:

```
with SUBQUERY as ( select * from mytable WHERE CONDITION)  
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
(
SELECT COL1 FROM SUBQUERY 
UNION
SELECT COL2 FROM SUBQUERY 
UNION
SELECT COL3 FROM SUBQUERY 
UNION
SELECT COL4 FROM SUBQUERY 
UNION
SELECT COL5 FROM SUBQUERY 
)
```

For more information look here: [with clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause)

Comment: in my case it cost more than the individual union queries

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an older version of Oracle, you can use a `cross join`:

```
select distinct (case when n.n = 1 then col1
                      when n.n = 2 then col2
                      when n.n = 3 then col3
                      when n.n = 4 then col4
                      when n.n = 5 then col5
                 end) as col
from subquery cross join
     (select 1 as n from dual union all
      select 2 from dual union all
      select 3 from dual union all
      select 4 from dual union all
      select 5 from dual
     ) n
where . . .;
```

Personally, I prefer a lateral join to `pivot`, because lateral joins are more powerful (although in this case they do the same thing).  That syntax looks like:

```
select distinct x.col
from subquery s cross apply
     (select s.col1 as col from dual union all
      select s.col2 from dual union all
      select s.col3 from dual union all
      select s.col4 from dual union all
      select s.col5 from dual
     ) x
where . . .;
```